# Uninstalled Ubuntu but still get Grub menu

Tags: grub2

I get the Grub menu still even though I installed Ubuntu on a separate partition which is now deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want to get rid of Grub and just go back into booting direct to Windows?

You can use [`bootrec /fixmbr`](http://windowsforum.com/threads/how-to-remove-grub-loader-and-get-windows-7-boot-loader-back-uninstalling-linux.34709/) from Windows to overwrite it.